# JavaFX EventHandling on final and effectively final variables

Tags: java, javafx

So here is part of a code snippet:

```
for (int col=1;col<=7;col++) {
    for (int row=2;row<=31;row++) {
        if (col!=4) {
            b = new Button();
            b.setText(Seat.calcID(row, col));
            b.setMinSize(2, 2);
            b.setFont(new Font(8));
            addableSeat.change(x, row, col);
            System.out.println(row+" "+col);
            b.setOnAction(e->{
                book.addSeat(Seat.genSeat(x, row, col));
                System.out.println(">>>"+addableSeat.accessId()+"<<<");
            });
            no=(col>4)?col+1:col;
            grid.setConstraints(b,no,row);
            grid.getChildren().add(b);
        }
    }
}
```

There is an error which states that the variables "row" and "col" within the eventhandler must be final or effectively final. How can I achieve that?

If you need additional code snippets I am willing to provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases adopt the simple common solution proposed by [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52620097/3992939).
In some cases you may prefer to declare `row` and `col` as class variables (fields):

```
private int row, col; 

    for (col=1;col<=7;col++) {
        for (row=2;row<=31;row++) {
            if (col!=4) {
                ...
                ...
                b.setOnAction(e->{
                    book.addSeat(Seat.genSeat(x, row, col));
                 });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you have made an answer, you could probably make it more complete. For example, you could use an `IntegerProperty` to wrap each `row` and `col`. Maybe also mention that using this approach is useful when you need to change the value from the anonymous class or lambda expression.

Comment: @Jai Thank you for your input. Would you add it to your answer to make it more complete ? (I am not sure I would use `IntegerProperty` just for this ).  I think your answer is the right approach in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the value of `row` and `col` is expected to change over time via `row++` and `col++`, so the compiler knows that it is neither `final`, nor is it *effectively* `final`.

The only *simple* way (that I can think of) to solve this is to declare additional local variables.

```
final int r = row;
final int c = col;
b.setOnAction(e->{
    book.addSeat(Seat.genSeat(x, r, c));
    System.out.println(">>>"+addableSeat.accessId()+"<<<");
});
```

If you want some slightly more advanced approach, there is this "wrapper" approach.

```
final IntegerProperty col = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
final IntegerProperty row = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
for (col.set(1);col.get()<=7;col.set(col.get()+1)) {
    for (row.set(2);row.get()<=31;row.set(row.get()+1)) {
        if (col.get()!=4) {
            ...
            ...
            b.setOnAction(e->{
                book.addSeat(Seat.genSeat(x, row.get(), col.get()));

                // I can even change value from the handler
                row.set(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Why this works is because `row` and `col` are now of object type (rather than primitive type), and they are `final`. Since the object references are passed into the `EventHandler`, the handler is free to use them and the wrapped values - this includes changing the internal values.

The approach mentioned by c0der is simply a variation of this. Instead of creating new object instances to wrap the values, the values are wrapped in the original containing class.

However, don't get me wrong - this approach does **not** work for your case. I decided to include here because this is another way to avoid the `final` and effectively `final` problem.

Using the wrapped approach (both c0der's and mine) will produce a different behavior. This is because the value of `row` and `col` is now shared. Since the `for` loops executes so fast that it is almost impossible for any human to trigger the event in between, the final value of `row` and `col` will become `32`and `8` respectively. This means that *all* the `Seat.genSeat(x, row, col)` will effectively become `Seat.genSeat(x, 32, 8)`.

Comment: Another option is to declare `row` and  `col` as class variables (fields).

Comment: @c0der Yeah, that is basically wrapper approach, and it's too complex for such a simple context here. That can be used only if you want "write access."